# efficient merge-purge of large files in python

Tags: python, mailmerge, record-linkage

I have two files to merge (left join) to identify which records from the left file are returned with matching rows from the right file.

The match key is based on a selection of columns defining postal data. I'm looking into ways to define the matching threshold and assign a unique key to unique addresses for duplicate management. This is also called householding, and it means that new matches do not reduce processing.

The real challenge is running the main matching loop efficiently for very large files.

This setup is probably a good candidate for map/reduce, but I'd like to explore self-contained (as in 'less naive') solutions for now.

I've checked [Most efficient way in Python to iterate over a large file (10GB+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215523/most-efficient-way-in-python-to-iterate-over-a-large-file-10gb) but since the right table is revisited over and over again, there might be an optimal structure specific for this exercise.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
import csv
import StringIO
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

cols1 = [ 1 , 3 , 4]
f1 = '''x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
     the,quick,brown,fox,jumps
     over,the,lazy,dogs,back,
     bla,bla,bla,bla,bla'''

 cols2 = [ 2 , 3 , 4]
 f2 = '''x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
      the,fast,brown,fox,jumps
      over,many,snoozing,dogs,back,
      the,prompt,fuchsia,fox,jumps
      over,the,lazy,dogs,back,
      bl,the,bl,bl,fox'''


 def standardize( x , selection , field_lengths=None ):
     y = ','.join([ x[selection[i]] for i in range(len(selection)) ])
     return y

 f1 = StringIO.StringIO(f1)
 f2 = StringIO.StringIO(f2)

 reader1 = csv.reader( f1 )
 reader2 = csv.reader( f2 )

 keys2 = []
 for row in reader2:
     # standardize and load key
     keys2.append( standardize( row , cols2 ) )

 for row in reader1:
     # standardize and compare
     key1 = standardize( row , cols1 )
     # ------------------------------------------------
     matches = [ fuzz.ratio( key1 , k) for k in keys2 ]
     # ------------------------------------------------
     max_match = max( matches )
     max_pos = [i for i, x in enumerate(matches) if x == max_match ][0]
     print key1 , "-->" , keys2[max_pos] , ':' , max_match
```

Comment: If you care so much about memory you can avoid allocating `list`s in your last loop, doing something like: `max_pos, max_match = max(((i, fuzz.ratio(key1, k) for i, k in enumerate(keys2)), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])); print key1, "-->", keys2[max_pos], ':', max_match`.

Comment: The fastest and easiest way would be to load the data into a database and add a index over the key. A index is what you want, but reinventing a database to do this memory efficient will be quite a bit of work.

Comment: Are the files sorted by any chance?

Comment: Bakuriu: good point, thanks. Jochen: I'm working in sqlite3 indexed over key once zipcode is matched for both address files. Alexis: the files are not sorted. Wouldn't variations in spelling within key fields in both files defeat the pre-sorting approach?